# Устаревший метод setAudioStreamType

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Разрабатываю приложение `Online Radio` и у меня возникла следующая проблема: Android Studio ругается на устаревший метод `setAudioStreamType`. Нужно использовать `AudioAtributes`, но у меня ничего не получается. Помогите с кодом.

```
package com.rock.onlineradio;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b_play;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started = false;

    String stream = "http://icecast.radiomaximum.cdnvideo.ru:8000/max_m.aac";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
        b_play.setEnabled(false);
        b_play.setText("LOADING");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

        b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (started) {
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    b_play.setText("PLAY");
                } else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    b_play.setText("PAUSE");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            return prepared;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            b_play.setEnabled(true);
            b_play.setText("PLAY");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (started) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (started) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(prepared) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mPlayer = new SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(5)
        .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setLegacyStreamType(mAudioStreamType)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build())
        .build();
    } else {
        // ваш старый код
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А это обязательно менять, или старый код тоже будет работать, считаясь устаревшим?

Comment: Будет работать, до тех пор пока не выйдет API новой версии, в котором уже не будет метода  `setAudioStreamType`.  И даже в этом случае можно просто использовать предыдущую версию API через `compileSdkVersion`. Тем не менее, я рекомендую готовить изменения насколько можно раньше.